# how to calculate total time between begin and end timestamps across multiple records in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp

I have a postgresql 9.1 table with begin and end timestamps that record time periods that may overlap for a userid. Example:

```
Userid   Begin                     End
1        2014-01-19 21:14:59+00    2014-01-19 21:30:00+00
2        2014-01-19 21:19:29+00    2014-01-19 21:40:30+00
1        2014-01-19 21:16:29+00    2014-01-19 21:31:30+00
3        2014-01-19 21:15:22+00    2014-01-19 21:30:29+00
2        2014-01-19 21:29:59+00    2014-01-19 21:45:00+00
3        2014-01-19 21:15:25+00    2014-01-19 21:35:10+00
4        2014-01-19 22:00:01+00    2014-01-19 22:05:20+00
```

I need to get the sum of all minutes per Userid across these rows ensuring that time is not double counted for the individual Userid, so that the output would be:

```
Userid   Hour      Total Minutes
1        21        n
2        21        n
3        21        n
4        22        n
```

Comment: Using `tzrange`'s `+` (range union) operator would be interesting for this. It's a pity it doesn't support discontinuities; that makes it enough harder that I stopped playing with it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a hard problem, but at least Postgres has `lag()` functionality.

Here is the idea.  Assuming that you have overlaps.  Find the first element that has no overlap.  Give it a flag value of 1.  Then do a cumulative sum of this value.  The result is that the different time periods are now assigned values according to their "islands".  Then simple aggregation works.

The following will work in many circumstances, using `lag()`:

```
select userid, sum(secs) / 60 as minutes
from (select userid, Island, min(begin) as begin, max(end) as end,
             extract(epoch from max(end) - min(begin)) as secs
      from (select t.*,
                   sum(IslandBegin) over (partition by userid order by begin) as Island
            from (select t.*,
                         (case when lag(end) over (partition by userid order by begin) >= begin
                               then 0
                               else 1
                          end) as IslandBegin
                  from table t
                 ) t
           ) t
      group by userid, Island
     ) t
group by userid;
```

Note that `end` is a reserved word, so adjust the code accordingly.

The above does not always work.  It assumes that the overlap is with the previous begin, and that might not be the case.  Consider {(1, 100), (2, 5), (8, 10)}.  I think the right logic still requires a correlated subquery.  The innermost query needs to change from:

```
            from (select t.*,
                         (case when lag(end) over (partition by userid order by begin) >= begin
                               then 0
                               else 1
                          end) as IslandBegin
                  from table t
                 ) t
```

to:

```
            from (select t.*,
                         coalesce((select 1
                                   from table t2
                                   where t2.end >= t.begin and
                                         t2.begin < t.begin
                                   limit 1
                                  ), 0
                                 ) as IslandBegin
                  from table t
                 ) t
```

Actually, that wasn't so bad, and I learned that `lag()` can't be used for all such cases.

Comment: In trying this code after changing the table names to the live ones, it returns column (15) "isbegin" does not exist. I changed that to IslandBegin and reran. It came back with: 'more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression'

Comment: @Steve . . . That should be `IslandBegin`.

Comment: Could be interesting to incorporate `tzrange` and its `+` operator into this.

Comment: @gordon-linoff as per my previous comment, I changed it to IslandBegin but it came back with the second error in my previous comment.

Comment: @gordon-linoff   I have tested this code. I ran it on 1 days worth of records (5742) but it just kept running so killed it. Then ran it on 1 hours data (824 records). This ran for 91597ms and returned 6960 rows.

Comment: @gordon-linoff   .... even though there are only 102 distinct userids in the table. Here are some of the records returned (userid;minutes):
51;17026.2333333333
53;14.0666666666667
54;19778.1666666667
59;930.4
60;19763.15
62;19758.65
63;180.15
66;150.133333333333
67;4362.06666666667
71;190.46666666666
As you can see, it reports some very large number of minutes per userid for just one hours data. Any ideas?

Comment: @Steve . . . The time stamps `begin` and `end` are never modified by the query -- I mean, they always match to something in the original data.  That means that either the final `sum()` is off, or the date/time arithmetic is weird (perhaps the data, perhaps the code).